# Python - Panel data create indicator with if statement

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I am trying to create an indicator equal to 1 if my meeting_date variable matches my date variable, and zero otherwise. I am getting an error in my code that consists of the following:
*ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().*

Please let me know what I am doing wrong! Here is my code:

```
    if crsp_12['meeting_date'] == crsp_12['date']:
        crsp_12['i_meeting_date_dayof'] == 1
    else:
        crsp_12['i_meeting_date_dayof'] == 0
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that `crsp_12['meeting_date']` and/or `crsp_12['date']` are _columns_ containing many values.  Some may be equal, and some may not be.  Is your intent to compare _the entire column_, or to compare _individual values within the column_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always avoid classical `if`/`for` constructs with pandas. Use vectorial code:

```
crsp_12['i_meeting_date_dayof'] = crsp_12['meeting_date'].eq(crsp_12['date']).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! What if I wanted an indicator for if a date falls inbetween two other dates?

Comment: Then you would use [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html).